# How to utilize generic AJAX call with multiple success functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an ajax call that returns XML. This XML needs to be handled differently based upon the section of the page within the site the user is on. Thus, I would like to implement 1 ajax function that makes the calls, and has a variable success function... I'm sure it is simple but I've searched for a while and cannot figure it out..

```
function makeAjaxCall(variableSuccessFunction) {
    $.ajax.... (ajax stuff goes here)...
    success: variableSuccessFunction(xml)
}
function ViewOne(xml) {
    //take the XML and update the dom as appropriate
}
function ViewTwo(xml) {
    //take the XML and update the dom as appropriate
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //be able to call either one of these functions
    makeAjaxCall(ViewOne);
    makeAjaxCall(ViewTwo);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've basically got it! Just one tweak:

```
function makeAjaxCall(variableSuccessFunction) {
    $.ajax.... (ajax stuff goes here)...
    success: variableSuccessFunction // no (xml)
}
```

You're passing around function references. `success` is passed a reference to `variableSuccessFunction` (whatever that may be) and will call it just like it would if you had supplied an anonymous function to it. No need to invoke it inside of `makeAjaxCall`.

Comment: cool thank you! I tried all sorts of different combinations and this works!